# Is $f(x) + (i-x)f'(x)$ concave for convex $f$ and $i \in \{0,1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable and convex. Define $\alpha: \mathbb R \times \{0,1\} \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by letting $$\alpha(x,i) = f(x) + (i-x)f'(x),$$ and let $$F(x,y) = x\alpha_1(y) + (1-x)\alpha_0(y).$$

So, in general, we know that $F$ has a critical point at $y = x$.

From what I understand about an often cited result on the literature of scoring rules (see e.g. Gneiting and Raftery, "[Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27639845)"), it is known that for a fixed $x$, $F(x,y)$ *restricted to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$* is *maximized* at $y=x$.

That all makes me think $F$ must be concave *when restricted to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$*. Is that so?

(**Updated**: I added the restriction to the unit square in response to some of the comments below.)

**Last update**: So the answer to this is indeed 'no'. But if I understand lemma 14 of [this paper](http://mark.reid.name/bits/pubs/colt15.pdf), though, $\alpha_i$ is quasi-concave.

Comment: If $f(x) = \exp(x)$, then $\alpha(x,i)$ is neither convex nor concave, having an inflection point at $i-1$.

Comment: Right. I guess what I'm interested in the restriction of $F$ to [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\sin x$ is convex on $[\pi,2\pi]$. The functions $\sin x-x\cos x$ and $\sin x+(1-x)\cos x$ are neither convex nor concave on this interval.

For the sine function, If $F$ were concave, then $F(1,y)=2\sin y-2y\cos y+\cos y$ were also concave as a function of one variable, but this is not the case.

Comment: Got it. I probably should have said more about the intended application. The main interest is in the restriction of the relevant functions to the unit interval or unit square. The relevant variation on your example would have us focus on $f(x) = \sin(\pi x+\pi)$, which would be convex on $[0,1]$. But I take it $-\sin( \pi x) - (x-y)\cos(\pi x)$ is concave on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?